# jQuery Ajax = success return page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Ok so I know long hand ajax but trying to use the jQuery short cut.  I have two documents

1. form.php
2. submit.php

In my "form" page I am calling the "submit" page to process the insert.  I am currently using the jquery ajax:

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
   jQuery('form').submit(function() {   
   string = jQuery("form").serializeArray();
   jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "submit.php", 
   data: string,
   dataType: "json",
   })   
   return false; 
   }); 
   </script>
```

When I view firebug it is processing the ajax fine.  I am getting 200 and post parameters are set.  What I am trying to do is have the ajax return the submit.php file.  I know it has something to do with the "success" function but I don't know how to add this.  I tried a few things like:

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
   jQuery('form').submit(function() {   
   string = jQuery("form").serializeArray();
   jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "submit.php", 
   data: string,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(html){
   alert(html);
   }
   })   
   return false; 
   }); 
   </script>
```

and

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
   jQuery('form').submit(function() {   
   string = jQuery("form").serializeArray();
   jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "submit.php", 
   data: string,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(html){
   $('.result').html(data);
   }
   })   
   return false; 
   }); 
   </script>
```

but neither of these are working.  Again I am simply trying to send the ajax request and then return the contents of the submit.php page.  Not only does the submit.php page hold the script to process the php/ajax insert but it also display success statements like "insert was successful" so that is why I need to not only run the script in the page but also return the contents of that page.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please start indenting your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chagne the `dataType:'json'` to `dataType:'html'` for the `callback` that you wish to display the contents of `submit.php`.

Comment: On which example.  I have three above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You were close in your second attempt, but you made a typo. Try:

```
success: function (data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
}
```

Also, unless your server is returning JSON, you probably want to change the `dataType`:

```
dataType: "html"
```

Comment: `data` is the parameter as a function. If you call `$('.result').html(data);` later, and `data` does not exist (because you've used `success: function (html) {`), then the function will return an error.